# Formatting a table in Lua with string.gsub

Tags: lua, formatting, gsub, lua-table

The following code formats a table into a printable string, but I feel like this can be done a lot easier.

```
function printFormat(table)
    local str = ""

    for key, value in pairs(table) do
        if value == 1 then
            str = str .. string.gsub(value, 1, "A, ") -- Replaces 1 with A
        elseif value == 2 then
            str = str .. string.gsub(value, 2, "B, ") -- Replaces 2 with B
        elseif value == 3 then
            str = str .. string.gsub(value, 3, "C, ") -- Replaces 3 with C
        elseif value == 4 then
            str = str .. string.gsub(value, 4, "D, ") -- Replaces 4 with D
        end
    end
    str = string.sub(str, 1, #str - 2) -- Removes useless chars at the end (last comma and last whitespace)
    str = "<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">" .. str .. "</font>" -- colors the string

    print(str)
end

local myTable = {1,4,3,2,3,2,1,3,4,2,2,...}
printFormat(myTable)
```

Is there a way to use a oneliner instead of having to loop through every index and make changes?

Or make the code more compact?

Comment: `str=table.concat(myTable,', '):gsub('%d+',{['1']='A',['2']='B',['3']='C',['4']='D'})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a helper table to replace the multiple `if` statement:

```
local chars = {"A", "B", "C", "D"}
for _, v in ipairs(t) do
    str = str .. chars[v] .. ", "
end
```

Or, if there are more than `1` to `4`, try this:

```
for _, v in ipairs(t) do
    str = str .. string.char(string.byte('A') + v) .. ", "
end
```

Comment: I ended choosing this answer because it was more flexible because of the for loop, even tho hjpotter's was more compact. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`table.concat`](https://devdocs.io/lua/index#pdf-table.concat).
2. [`string.gsub`](https://devdocs.io/lua/index#pdf-string.gsub) can perform replacement using a replacement table.
3. Don't use names like `table` for your own variables.

Therefore:

```
function printFormat( tInput )
    local sReturn = table.concat( tInput, ', ' )
    sReturn = sReturn:gsub( '%d', {['1'] = 'A', ...} ) -- update table accordingly
    return '<font color="#FFFFFF">' .. str .. "</font>"
end
```

and, for one liner:

```
return '<font color="#FFFFFF">' .. ( table.concat(tInput, ', ') ):gsub( '%d', {['1'] = 'A', ...}  )
```

Comment: I really like this piece of code. Thx for posting it! Any ideas on how to add a smart counter for 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' to your code? (e.g. how many times did A occur, how many times B, etc..)